# mvvmlight eventtocommand modifiers

Tags: mvvm, keyboard, mvvm-light, eventtocommand

I'm looking for a solution of adding modifiers to EventToCommand usign mvvm light. What I want to achieve is binding a command to let's say mouseEnter but only if the ctrl is pressed. Below I have just a mouseenter command.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TestCmd}"/>
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Any idea how to add keyboard modifier to it?

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
TestCmd = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
    // command action here

}, () => Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use the CanExecute feature of RelayCommand.

a solution could be :

```
TestCmd= new RelayCommand<MouseEventArgs>(e =>
{
     // do your command
},   e =>
{
     return (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Control) > 0;
});
```